# if callable throws timeoutexception java with streams open

Tags: java, io

I'm using a callable to open some inputstreams enclosed in finally blocks, which for some annoying reason are throwing premature eof exceptions for reasons i dont care about. i want to give the callable a certain amount of time and then shut it off if its not finished. but how do i also shut off the stuff inside the finally block inside the callable?
For example, in the following code the finally block printing "e" never gets executed.

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Integer> f = e.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while(i<1) {
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("e");
        }
        return 4;
    }
});


try {
    Integer i = f.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch(Exception ef) {
    System.out.println("l");
}
```

Comment: What is an 'input stream enclosed in [a] finally block'? Why don't you care about the premature EOFs? What do you mean by 'shut off the stuff inside the finally block'? What does your example have to do with your question? This is all most unclear.

Comment: i have inputstreams getting opened inside a callable. i want them to be shut off when and if the callable runs out of time, and i want the executor service to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are barking up the wrong tree. If the streams are socket input streams, you should use Socket.setSoTimeout() to enforce a read timeout, or HttpURLConnection.setReadimeout() if they are HTTP streams. Databases have timeouts. Everything that can block in a read that I can think of has a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` block in the code sample you've provided never executes because there is not any path for the execution to escape the `while` loop. If the `while` loops terminating condition were met or there was some piece of code that could possibly `throw` a `RuntimeException` then you would see the sysout.

Comment: that was on purpose to simulate a stream. what do i do if i want to terminate a stream after a timeout in the above code.

Comment: Declare a `final` local variable containing the time when you would like execution to end and check it with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: i was looking for a way to do that from the executorservice or something.